# nHibernate - subselect in select with order by

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have conversations with many messages and I want to order the conversations in order of the created date of the last message in ConversationMessages table.

How would I write this in a queryOver in nHibernate. Should I use subQuery?

```
select distinct c.ConversationId,
  (select max(CreatedDate) 
    from tConversationMessage mess where mess.ConversationId = c.ConversationId
  ) as LastMessage 
from tConversation c order by LastMessage
```

Answer (score 3):

With some guessing of your C# naming, NHibernate mapping... this would be the way:

```
Conversation conversation = null;
ConversationMessage message = null;

// the subselect of a max
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<ConversationMessage>(() => message)
    .Where(() => message.Conversation.ID == conversation.ID)
    .Select(Projections.Max("CreatedDate"));

// the alias of the Conversation to be injected into subquery
var query = session.QueryOver<Conversation>(() => conversation);

// a select and group by (distinct) clause
query.SelectList(l => l
    .SelectGroup(s => conversation.ID)
    .Select(Projections.SubQuery(subQuery))
    );

// Order by the max Created date (asc)
var list = query
    .OrderBy(Projections.SubQuery(subQuery))
        .Asc
    .List<object[]>()
    ;
```

and for each Conversation ID we will get the max(CreateDate) of ConversationMessage